# Contact form not working with PHP

Tags: php, macos

I'm using this tutorial on [**nettuts**](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/build-a-neat-html5-powered-contact-form/) to build a contact form. Their contact form works fine on a mac that's running on 10.6.8 but doesn't work on a mac running on 10.8.4? I'm assuming it might be something to do with version of PHP but I'm not sure how to fix their code to make it paly nice can anyone help? I have also tried it on my websites server but no joy there either.

thanks,

Comment: What *exactly* doesn't work and You've tried to do?

Comment: Not sure exactly when I send fill the thing out on os 10.8 it does nothing, when I do exactly the same thing on 10.6.8 the form works.

Comment: Is there anyway I can run a test to see what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of php, you can use a button with a mailto: tag

```css
.button {
  background-color: #ffa200;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 410px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button:hover
{
 background-color:#ff2f00;
}

a.a
{
 text-decoration: none;
}
h3.k
{
 color: white;
 font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<center>
<button class="button">
<a class="a" href="mailto: name@example.com"><h3 class="k">SEND US A MESSAGE</h3></a>
</button>
</center>
```

This tag opens the Mail app and already shows who it is to